# Cypress test returns to the login page after clicking the button in another page

Tags: cypress

I am trying to put a cypress test where after login to the baseUrl page, it moves to the second page. When I click on a button in the second page, it kicks the test back to the login page. I did try this, but it did not work.

```
cy.visit(Cypress.env('baseUrl')+"/admin);
```

Comment: at least say something before you put it down :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This fixed the issue. Source:https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/cookies.html#Preserve-Once

```
Cypress.Cookies.preserveOnce('SessionID', 'auth_cookie');
```

Comment: Please be more specific about where to put the code.

Answer (score 1):

That indicates the redirected page is not online and cypress tries to go to the baseurl. Check if all the consoles for the project are started and compiled correctrly and rerun the test